# Memory strategy when using IOCP

Tags: c++, windows, networking

I am new to Windows IOCP, currently I am rewriting the network part of our server using IOCP. I am trying to figure out how to handle the memory (Overlapped / WSABUF objects).I have a little struct that derives from OVERLAPPED and contains a WSABUF and a few other fields.

I tried keeping a ring buffer these objects and reusing them, but it didn't work. I thought that when the completion routine is called, one of the objects will be passed back to me and I can mark it as available again.

When I allocate them on the heap (and keep in a vector), how do I know when it's safe to delete/reuse them?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: "it didn't work" - what?

Comment: Your assumption is correct; you can reuse the OVERLAPPED structure once the completion routine has been called.  If that's not working, there's a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: ... the most common mistake is to allocate them on the stack (i.e., to use a local variable) rather than on the heap.

Comment: you must use reference counting on this struct. when you pass pointer to it (via `OVERLAPPED`) parameter to io call - you need increment reference count - just *before* io call. when your io is complete (by dequeue  overlapped or just with error) - you decrement reference count to struct (after you finish use it in completion) this is work perfect

Comment: so you never direct call delete. you call *AddRef* / *Release*. on struct. you create struct with `dwRef==1`. pass it to some io call and just call *Release*. call *AddRef* *before* pass struct to io - because you really pass pointer to your struct in api (which you got back in completion). call *Release* if io failed just or when you remove struct back from iocp and finish use it. at this point (when you dequeue it and process data) or after io fail - you can reuse it.

Comment: however if you want reuse *data buffers* - need understand that you reuse it only in user mode. in kernel - on every new io - it mapped/unmapped via MDL every time. for do this only once, but not per every single io - begin from win8 you can use pre-registered buffers (already mapped to kernel) the [`Registered Input/Output (RIO) API Extensions`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997032(v=ws.11).aspx) probably the best choice in your case

Comment: Harry Johnson: I have a vector of these structs.

Comment: RbMm: Thanks for the elaborate answer, I will add reference counting. Hopefully it solves the issue.

Comment: RbMm: I think that my issue is that I have WSABUF as a member of my struct.

Comment: correct way have 3 type of structs: 1) per socket, wich encapsulate socket handle and state (for tcp, for udp we in general can have single socket for all) 2) for every data buffer 3) struct like [`IRP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550694(v=vs.85).aspx) - per every IO operation. this structure must be inherited (or containing) from `OVERLAPPED` and pointers to 1) and 2) structs. also some additional operation context (say tag - are this send or recv). before pass pounter (3) to IO - you increment reference on it

Comment: the kernel save pointer to your (3) struct at `IRP.UserIosb` and return to you back when io complete. so in completion you have pointer to (3) and via it pointer to data buffers(2) and socket data (1). here you release (3). in (3) destructor release (2) and (1). AddRef/Release logic need for all here

Comment: RbMm: Thanks a lot. Currently I don't have a reference count, but a simple available/busy flag, I guess this is not enough, is it?

Comment: my personal vision that reference counting here the best way for manage object lifetime when it access  from many threads at once. here main need understand - when you pass pointer to overlapped (to WSASend[To], `WSARecv[From]`, ConnectEx..) - you pass pointer to own object. so you must `AddRef` before call. if call fail - just call Release. otherwise call Release in completion, when you finish work with object.

Comment: RbMm: Thanks a lot. I am clear about Overlapped objects. What about WSABUF? From what I saw when WSASendTo is called, I can pass a WSABUF allocated on the stack. Obviously the WSABUF object being passed to WSARecvFrom has to be in memory when the completion routine is called. Can I reuse a single WSABUF object?

Comment: Note that you don't *need* to use reference counting.  I believe that what RbMm is saying is that reference counting is the most reliable way of avoiding bugs in your code that might prematurely reuse a structure.  It isn't clear to me whether that's actually your problem, though, since as far as I can see you haven't yet described what the symptoms are.

Comment: the `WSABUF` can be temporary object and allocated as local variable in stack. but `WSABUF.buf` must be alive and not changed until io operation not complete

Comment: @RbMm is correct, turns out that is documented in `WSASend` and `WSARec`: "If this function is completed in an overlapped manner, it is the Winsock service provider's responsibility to capture the WSABUF structures before returning from this call. This enables applications to build stack-based WSABUF arrays pointed to by the lpBuffers parameter."